# Fitting tires on Reynolds Strike SLG

Tags: tire, wheels, rims

I've been trying to fit Michelin Power Competition (AirComp inners) onto a set of Strike's. (I'm certain these are true, they were default fitted with other tires, and these had 0% wobble.) Let's just say the wheels haven't been treating me so well. I've outfitted numerous box-type wheelsets without an issue. This is a whole different story.

The fitting took me about an hour in total because it's so damn tight (after much hassle I've succesfully put the tires).

After inflating, spinning the wheel makes the tires look hopelessly wobbly. When I inflate to higher pressure, say 6-7 bars, I hear "clinging" noises coming from the tire that becomes seated better/closer to the edge of the rim. It doesn't look good, and I decide to fit them again.

Result: Same thing. Nothing changed. Wobbly tires. Tires that make all kinds of bangs. And again. And again. I've been trying this all day long.

I have no idea how to fit these tires on these wheels...

Any tips on some kind of workflow / hints / secrets, so I can put this issue to rest?

Comment: I've had tight tyres that needed considerably more than their max pressure to seat nicely and made quite a loud noise when they did.  They were also hard to fit initially (they're better now but still not great).  Wetting the rubber/rim as a lubricant can help. Some people say use soapy water; I just use plain, which isn't as effective.  I think we've already got an answer on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a very tight tire back on the rim?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-get-a-very-tight-tire-back-on-the-rim) also [Tyre has a 'dip' in it after fitting to rim](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/21785/7309)

Comment: @ChrisH Thanks for your comment. The "Tire has a dip" question is identical, but has no solution...

Comment: @ChrisH The tight tire  answer doesn't work for me. I'm not getting any extra space by doing that. Can't feel my fingers anymore atm...

Comment: I think the "dip" question was solved but the OP never came back. Unfortunately our best ideas are at those two questions already.

Comment: I know, product recommendation, yada yada, but Michelins are known to be tight and difficult to mount on some rims. Vittoria on the other hand is commonly thought to be slightly oversized and easier to mount.